# Web cam not getting detected

Tags: 14.04, webcam, lts

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop. Previously it was Windows. Earlier my laptop's webcam was working fine, but now it isn't. I don't think it's due to hardware failure. It's annoying as I do Skype so often.

My laptop is **Sony vaio vpceh25en (Intel core i3, 2gb, nvidia410m)** is with built-in webcam. Please help me.

Comment: Add more details about your system and webcam